# What versions of eclipse and apache tomcat should I use with jdk-6u30?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jdk6

I am configuring the env on Vista. I have jdk-6u30 and eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32 installed on the system. Please suggest what tomcat version would be compatible? I tried installing apache-tomcat-7.0.25 but it gave me "requested resource not available error" hen I tested it for the first time. What is the reason of this error on first test? Is it something to do with the compatibility issue or choosing wrong way of installation? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very newest versions of both Eclipse and Tomcat will work perfectly with that version of Java; you must have made some mistake in installing or testing.

Comment: I was making a mistake while installation. Thanks :)